# st_intersection by id

Tags: r, sf

I create two buffer around points and want to intersect the two buffers by id (creating a doughnut) around each point. With st_intersection I can only manage to get all possible intersections, resulting in many more new polygons than I have points.

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(dplyr)

data    <- data.frame(id = paste0("ID_", 1:20), lon = runif(20, -10, 10), lat = runif(20, -10, 10))
data_sf <- st_as_sf(data,coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% st_transform(CRS("+proj=laea"))

bfr1 <- data_sf %>% st_buffer(150000)
bfr2 <- data_sf %>% st_buffer(450000)

inters1 <- st_intersection(bfr1, bfr2)

### I tried (with error)
bfr <- rbind(bfr1, bfr2)

hh <- bfr %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_intersection(geometry)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *st_intersection* will not result in what you want, as it will only return you the inner ring. This is the part where the two buffers are intersecting. What you want is *st_difference*: this will erase the inner buffer from the outer buffer resulting in a Donut. I hope I understood correctly that this is what you wanted. Keep in mind that when using *st_difference* you have to put the outer buffer first to be able to erase the smaller part from it.

Then there are **two possible ways** to solve your problem.

**1.** You can conduct a "filtering" of the difference result. As you said, a lot of differences are calculated, you could filter them by ID like this afterwards:

```
inters1 <- st_difference(bfr2, bfr1)    
final_inters1 <- inters1[which(inters1$id == inters1$id.1),]
```

**2.** You can apply the differencing beforehand by using *lapply* selecting every entity and applying the differencing to it. Thus, the other polygons will not be considered when doing the differencing. This is how I would code it, there are possibly nicer ways to do that - I am open for any suggestions.

```
inters <- lapply(1:nrow(data_sf), function(x){
  inters <- st_difference(bfr2[x,],bfr1[x,])
})
final_inters2 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,inters)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It is indeed st_difference. I like both ways!